# insert button inside dynamically created datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datatable

I need to insert a but "THIS IS WHERE I WANT THE BUTTON". How can I go about to do it?

Obviously the typeof data can't be string but what should I use? Html controllers?

```
public partial class Technician : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Fill_table();
    }

    private void Fill_table()
    {
        //creates table dynamically
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        //Adds column's name
        dt.Columns.Add("Ordem", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Estados", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Ficha Técnica", typeof(string));
        //Adds Rows
        dt.Rows.Add("Ordem X",THIS IS WHERE I WANT THE BUTTON, "Ficha Técnica");
        WorkList.DataSource = dt;
        WorkList.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your task is unclear. Please describe it in detail.

Comment: I would like to add a button on the 2nd Column. @Vladimir

Answer (score 0):

Add row like:

```
dt.Rows.Add("Ordem X", "", "Ficha Técnica");
```

In your RowDataBound event:

```
protected void WorkList_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    // CHECK IF ROW IS NOT IN EDIT MODE
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        // CREATE A Button
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.ID = "btnEstados";
        btn.Text = "Estados";

        // ADD BUTTON TO EACH ROW IN 2ND COLUMN
        e.Row.Cells[1].Controls.Add(btn);
    }
}
```

**Note:** Don't forget to add attribute `OnRowDataBound="WorkList_RowDataBound"` to your GridView.